# Google chart - Treemap não aparece

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-charts

Olá, estou tentando plotar um treemap com dados oriundos de um BD (mysql), porém, não aparece nada. Já tentei diversas alternativas e sem êxito. Já consegui plotar diversos gráficos, menos o treemap, acredito que o problema esteja na criação da tabela de dados do php.

Segue parte do php para buscar os dados:

```js
 $table = array();

   //colunas 
   $table['cols'] = array(

    array('label'=>'Rota','type'=>'string'),

    array('label'=>'Rota2','type'=>'string'),

                 array('label'=>'Entregas','type'=>'number'),

     array('label'=>'Entregas_cor','type'=>'number')
    );

   //rows
    $rows = array();
    
     $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(sk_carga) as qtd_entregas, carga_rota as rota FROM dim_lg_carga where id_empresa = :sk_empresa GROUP BY 2");

     $query->bindParam(':sk_empresa',$sk_empresa, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $query->execute();


       while ($linha=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      


        $rota =$linha['rota'];
        
        $rota2 =null;
        
       $qtd_entregas = intval($linha['qtd_entregas']);
        
        
      $qtd_entregas_cor = intval($linha['qtd_entregas']);

        $temp = array();

        $temp[] = array('v'=>$rota);

        $temp[] = array('v'=>$rota2);

        
        $temp[] = array('v'=>$qtd_entregas);

        $temp[] = array('v'=>$qtd_entregas_cor);


        $rows[] = array('c'=>$temp);
     }

      
      $table['rows'] = $rows;


       $jsonTable = json_encode($table);
       
       
       echo $jsonTable;
```

chamada JS:

```js
             google.setOnLoadCallback(desenharGraficoEntregasRotas);
   

      function desenharGraficoEntregasRotas(){
       // ajax
       
       var jsonDados10 = $.ajax({
       //url:"Model/Empresa/get_entregas_motorista.php",
       url:'http://localhost/sistema-bi-web/Model/Empresa/get_rotas_entregas.php',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false

       }).responseText;


      var options10 = {
              minColor: '#f00',
                  midColor: '#ddd',
                  maxColor: '#0d0',
                  headerHeight: 15,
                  fontColor: 'black',
                  showScale: true

      };
     
       //dados do grafico
       var dados10 = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonDados10);

      
      var grafico10= new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('grafico_entregas_rota'));

       // desenha o grafico de acordo com os parametros passados
       grafico10.draw(dados10, options10); 

  }
```

parte HTML:

```html
 <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="canvas-wrapper">
      <div id="grafico_entregas_rota"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

Exemplificação Banco de dados:
sk_carga coluna_rota
1..........Pituba
2..........Pituba
3..........Pituba
4..........Pituba
5..........Brotas
6..........Pituba
7..........Brotas
8..........Linha verde